# Kendo Menu dataSource imageUrl not accepting content

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui, icons, kendo-menu

I am using Kendo controls in my application. Where in I have a Menu control having datasource in my controller. Currently I am passing relative path of URL for imageUrl. But with increased application, now there are many calls going to backend. So I want to replace this url with ICOMOON content something like "/e654". Is there any option like this??

```
  dataSource: [
                    {
                        text: "",
                        imageUrl: "../../App/Modules/PIC/Styles/images/LUT_Small.png",
                        items: [
                            {
                                imageUrl: "../../App/Modules/PIC/Styles/images/viewer-colors-hotmetal.png",
                                cssClass: "picKendoMenuItemCss",
                                text: lutManager.presetColorLutNames.hotMetal,
                                spriteCssClass: "picKendospriteCss"
                            },
```

Instead of direct calls to png, i want to use ICOMOON content.

Help please.

Thanks,
-/Sammi

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use icomoon, I recommend to use fontawesome icons.

http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/controls/navigation/menu/how-to/using-fontawesome-icons

Comment: Thanks, solves problem to some extent. Using ICOMOON icons.making some tweaks.